# How to modify objects tree as a whole

Tags: java, hibernate

There's a company entity with child contact entities. UI contains company's card with a contacts grid.

I want user to open company's card, edit the company, add some new contacts to it, delete and modify some existing contacts. If user clicks "Cancel" no changes should be applied. If user clicks "Save" all the changes to the company and child contacts have to be applied.

How could we realize such logic using Java and Hibernate?

UPDATE

I see that my question may be misunderstood, so I'll try to reformulate.

The question is: what is a good Hibernate pattern for changing object tree (a parent with 1 or more levels of child sets or collections) as a whole? Should we, for example, load the parent object in memory with all the children, detach it, modify and then merge?

Comment: This question is a bit too broad to be answerable and is missing important details.  For example, is this a web application? How will the user make the changes?  In order to get an answer, you're much better off on focussing on specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

It aint so difficult. Example or yours below. Entities are in one-many relationship.

```
CompanyCards (one) --- Contacts(many)
```

Your entity will be as follows

```
public class CompanyCards implements Serializable{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy=company)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    public List<Contacts> contacts;

    //getters and setters

}
```

If you want to save the company and contacts just send `CompanyCards` detached object modified from the client to the server. (removing contacts / updating the Company / updating even the Contacts)

In hibernate you have to do `session.saveOrUpdate(companyCards)`. Hibernate will take care of updating the parent and the children. Provided you mention cascade type to `CascadeType.ALL`